# Executing executeMethod() is displaying exception using j2bugzilla API

Tags: api, automation, bugzilla

I have used j2bugzilla API for bugzilla integration .

I have used  executeMethod() for login , report a bug and finally to add an attachment.first two methods were executed successfully but when i use same method for adding attahcment it is generating error.

```
           image = ImageIO.read(new File(FILEPATH));
       baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
       byte[] res=baos.toByteArray();


          conn.executeMethod(login);

      f = new AttachmentFactory();
 attachment = f.newAttachment() 
 .setData(res)//Transform your File to Base64
 .setMime(MIME)
 .setName(NAME)
 .setSummary(SUMMARY)
 .createAttachment();


  conn.executeMethod(new AddAttachment(attachment,8361 ));
```

Now the last execute method is giving me the error. java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution , Issue was with my image MIME type. I changed the MIME type from img/png to image/png and it got worked